# Match controller action in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, if-statement, url, zend-framework

I want to add if condition in htaccess file for a controller action. The url is like

```
www.example.com/user/profile/5?cid=7&pos=1
```

I want to add condition in htaccess file if url is action "profile". I tried following:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == 'profile'">
        // do something
</If>
```

but it doesn't work. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `REQUEST_URI` is equal to `/user/profile/5?cid=7&pos=1` and not just `profile`, so your condition is not met.

If you want to catch if your `REQUEST_URI` **contains** `profile`, you can do this with a simple regex :

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /profile/">
    // do something
</If>
```